# Как сделать парсер protobuf бинарного пакета?

Tags: c#, google-protobuf

Нашел в инете информацию и примеры по сериализации и десериализации готовых классов в бинарник. А как сделать наоборот?

Например, на сервер приходят пакеты с данными которые необходимо разбирать руками побайтно. Я так понял, что с помощью protobuf можно сгенерировать классы на этот бинарник и десериализовать его. Подскажите как это делается на простейшем примере, пожалуйста.

Comment: как из бинарника восстановить proto файл?

Comment: @KoVadim, видимо да. Я с proto файлами не видел примеров, сериализация без них вроде работает.

Comment: без прото файла сериализация/десериализация будет работать. Они нужны только для того, что бы сгенерировать все нужные классы.

Но вот восстановить прото файл с бинарника нельзя. Там не сохраняются имена ключей. И если какое то optional поле не было добавлено, то также о нем не узнать.